# Wrong number of arguments while reversing a number in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am trying to write a program in Scheme that reverses a given number. However, the problem is that although I have got my recursion right, Scheme is saying that the number of arguments to my recursive call is not correct.

What is wrong in this code? Why do I get the error of wrong arguments?

```
(define (rev revs n)
    (cond ( (= n 0) 1)
        (else ( 
            (rev ( ( + (* revs 10) (remainder n 10) ) (quotient n 10) ) ) 
            ) )))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of erroneous parentheses, and the base case is wrong (you have to return the accumulator). Try this:

```
(define (rev revs n)
  (cond ((= n 0) revs)
        (else 
         (rev (+ (* revs 10) (remainder n 10)) (quotient n 10)))))
```

Remember, in Scheme parentheses mean "function application, if you surround something with `()` the interpreter will try to apply what's inside as a function. Be very, very careful where you put those `()`.

Comment: Also, it doesn't work. I am getting output as 1 only.

Comment: There's a problem with the algorithm, then. The question was about the syntax error. With what parameters are you calling the function?

Comment: Ah! I am sorry. My base case was wrong. I had to output `revs`.